# How to find an optimal combination of predictors in predicting outcome?

Tags: regression, outliers, normalization, cooks-distance

It is a marketing project in which I need to compare the effectiveness of six different marketing tools in terms of sales. the tools are like "No. of times a salesman personally visit to the customer", "How many times the discount is given" etc. The problem is to identify which one is the effective measure in terms of sales and what would be the optimal combination of advertising tool.

while plotting the scatter plot the relation between sales and advertising tools...it is not at all linear. Moreover the data (both outcome and predictors ) are highly skewed. The questions: As per the cook’s distance I found around 200 points as extreme outlier, which is around 0.5percent of data. What should I do with them? Can I drop them or do some imputation. How can I find the combination of two or more optimum techniques? What should be the best algorithm to model sales with the help of these six advertising techniques. All variables are continuous scale and highly skewed. Do I need to normalize them first? Thanks in advance.